# Can't get the right TensorFlow version when deploying a Flask app to Google Cloud Platform

Tags: python, tensorflow, google-cloud-platform, pip, yaml

I am trying to deploy a Python Flask application to Google Cloud Platform (App Engine). The app works fine locally on my computer. I use Tensorflow version 2.3.0 in my app. This seems to be a problem when I try to deploy the app to Google Cloud Platform. I get this error code in the build log when trying to build the app:

```
Collecting tensorflow==2.3.0 (from -r requirements.txt (line 2))
Step #1:   Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow==2.3.0 (from -r requirements.txt (line 2)) (from versions: 0.12.1, 1.0.0, 1.0.1, 1.1.0rc0, 1.1.0rc1, 1.1.0rc2, 1.1.0
, 1.2.0rc0, 1.2.0rc1, 1.2.0rc2, 1.2.0, 1.2.1, 1.3.0rc0, 1.3.0rc1, 1.3.0rc2, 1.3.0, 1.4.0rc0, 1.4.0rc1, 1.4.0, 1.4.1, 1.5.0rc0, 1.5.0rc1, 1.5.0, 1.5.1, 1.6.0rc0, 1.6.0rc1, 1.6.0, 1.7.0rc0, 1.7.0r
c1, 1.7.0, 1.7.1, 1.8.0rc0, 1.8.0rc1, 1.8.0, 1.9.0rc0, 1.9.0rc1, 1.9.0rc2, 1.9.0, 1.10.0rc0, 1.10.0rc1, 1.10.0, 1.10.1, 1.11.0rc0, 1.11.0rc1, 1.11.0rc2, 1.11.0, 1.12.0rc0, 1.12.0rc1, 1.12.0rc2, 
1.12.0, 1.12.2, 1.12.3, 1.13.0rc0, 1.13.0rc1, 1.13.0rc2, 1.13.1, 1.13.2, 1.14.0rc0, 1.14.0rc1, 1.14.0, 2.0.0a0, 2.0.0b0, 2.0.0b1)
Step #1: No matching distribution found for tensorflow==2.3.0 (from -r requirements.txt (line 2))
Step #1: You are using pip version 10.0.1, however version 20.2.3 is available.
Step #1: You should consider upgrading via the 'pip insll --upgrade pip' command.
Step #1: The command '/bin/sh -c pip install -r requirements.txt' returned a tanon-zero code: 1
Finished Step #1
ERROR
ERROR: build step 1 "gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker@sha256:c1128bf8a32cfe4f2efcb920551a71a43d3401d3a3631f8b745e90b75099b68e" failed: step exited with non-zero status: 1
Step #1:
```

Earlier in the build log, I get this:

```
Step 3/9 : RUN virtualenv --no-download /env -p python3.6
Step #1:  ---> Running in cd3673a277e1
Step #1: Running virtualenv with interpreter /opt/python3.6/bin/python3.6
Step #1: Using base prefix '/opt/python3.6'
Step #1: New python executable in /env/bin/python3.6
Step #1: Also creating executable in /env/bin/python
Step #1: Installing setuptools, pip, wheel...done.
Step #1: Removing intermediate container cd3673a277e1
```

As you see the App uses a Python 3.6 environment. How can I specify that I want to build my App in a Python 3.7 or 3.8 environment?

My requirement file looks like this:

```
pip==20.2.3
tensorflow==2.3.0
Flask==0.11.1
gunicorn==19.5.0
numpy==1.17.4
scipy==1.4.1
h5py==2.10.0
```

and my YAML file looks like this:

```yaml
entrypoint: "gunicorn -b:$PORT main:app"
env: flex
runtime: python
runtime_config: 
  python_version: 3
```

From the error code, I guess the question is: Why can't I find Tensorflow 2.3.0?
Is it related to the old python version or the old pip version? How do I install a more recent pip and Python version when deploying an app to Google Cloud Platform?

I tried to update pip in the Google Cloud Shell before deploying the application. I then got this warning:

```
********************************************************************************
Python 2 is deprecated. Upgrade to Python 3 as soon as possible.
See https://cloud.google.com/python/docs/python2-sunset
To suppress this warning, create an empty ~/.cloudshell/no-python-warning file.
The command will automatically proceed in  seconds or on any key.
********************************************************************************
DEPRECATION: Python 2.7 reached the end of its life on January 1st, 2020. Please upgrade your Python as Python 2.7 is no longer maintained. pip 21.0 will drop support for Python 2.7 in January 2
021. More details about Python 2 support in pip can be found at https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/development/release-process/#python-2-support pip 21.0 will remove support for this functionality.
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Requirement already up-to-date: pip in /home/bjorn_sing/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (20.2.3)
bjorn_sing@cloudshell:~/FlaskApp (my-first-flask-app-289008)$ pip3 install --upgrade pip
Cache entry deserialization failed, entry ignored
Collecting pip
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/4e/5f/528232275f6509b1fff703c9280e58951a81abe24640905de621c9f81839/pip-20.2.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Installing collected packages: pip
Successfully installed pip-20.2.3
```

Comment: looks like tensorflow 2.3.x cannot be installed in your cloud platform. Upgrade your pip `python -m pip install --upgrade pip`. If pip still cannot find tensorflow 2.3.0, then use this: `tensorflow==2.0.0b1` as this looks like the latest version that the current pip on the Google cloud platform has.

Comment: Where do I write ```python -m pip install --upgrade pip``` ? In requirement.txt or in app.yaml? Or do I write it somewhere else?

Comment: by using the cloud shell. Cloud Shell provides command-line access to the virtual machine instance in a terminal window that opens in the Google Cloud Console. You can open multiple shell connections to the same instance. Just run gcloud --help to view the gcloud command-line tool commands available to you.

Comment: I tried to run the command ```python -m pip install --upgrade pip``` but then it seems like I am running Python 2.7 (see last update above)

Comment: When I was running ```gcloud app deploy``` afterwards I got this message: ```pip version 10.0.1, however version 20.2.3 is available.```

Comment: I will better write it as answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I reproduced your setup in my own environment having the same error message as you and as far as I could see the issue seems to be with the pip version, tough maybe being in the Python3.6 runtime is also related.

One important thing to note is that when using the default runtimes provided by App Engine the configuration degree is limited which sometimes leads to incompatibilities across library versions and the like. For instance the Python runtime in App Engine Flexible still doesn't support Python3.8 while Standard App Engine does.

That said, a solution to stay with the Flexible Environment would be to use a [custom runtime](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/custom-runtimes/how-to) by providing your own Dockerfile in which you can specify whatever base image and runtime you'd like to. Here's an example Dockerfile and app.yaml I tested for this use case:

```
# Dockerfile
FROM python:3.8-slim

ENV APP_HOME /app
WORKDIR $APP_HOME
COPY . ./

RUN pip install --upgrade pip
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt

CMD exec gunicorn --bind :$PORT --workers 1 --threads 8 --timeout 0 main:app

-------------------

# app.yaml
runtime: custom
env: flex
```

That said, I also have to point out that shakhyar answer is not correct. While it's true that you can enable debug mode and SSH the VM holding your flexible instance all the changes made are temporary and will be lost as soon as debug mode is disabled. Furthermore, this process must be repeated for each an every instance and all security patches are turned off while in debug mode. Therefore, connecting to your instances wouldn't solve the problem. Documentation [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/custom-runtimes/debugging-an-instance)

Comment: Thanks for a very good answer @Happy-Monad ! After doing some research I think I will try to use Heroku to deploy my flask app.